# Loading Multiple Related Hierarchical Objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have below tables

**1. Address -> AddressID**
**2. Designation -> DesignationID**
**3. Stores -> StoreID, AddressId**
**4. Contacts -> ContactID, StoreID, DesignationID**
**5. ContactsAddresses => ContactID, AddressID**

and related NavigationProperties. I want to load all the Stores with all Contacts and their contact's associated Data (`Designation` and `ContactsAddresses`)

I tried something like below:

```
this.ObjectContext.Stores.Include("Contacts.Designation.ContactsAddresses")
   .Include("Address");
```

I have a doubt that when I write `Contacts.Designation.ContactsAddresses` -> whether it consider `ContactsAddresses` as `Contacts` navigation property or Designation's navigation Property. Cause I also need to include `Address` in  `ContactsAddresses`. Its multiple hierarchy which needs to be resolved.

I want to have each contact's Designation and all addresses. Can anyone please help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly specify the two include paths.

```
this.ObjectContext.Stores.Include("Contacts.Designation")
     .Include("Contacts.ContactsAddresses");
```

Comment: @TejasPatel Removed an extra property in second `Include` method. I tried this and worked.